# Show that $\frac{X+1}{n+2}$ is a biased estimator of the binomial parameter $\theta$

Tags: statistics

The problem is:

> Show that $\frac{X+1}{n+2}$ is a biased estimator of the binomial parameter $\theta$. Is this estimator asymptotically unbiased?

My way of doing this is following:

Calculate the expected value/mean of the estimator $\frac{X+1}{n+2}$: 
$E\Big[\frac{X+1}{n+2}\Big]=\Big({1\over n+2}\Big)E\Big[X+1\Big]=\Big({1\over n+2}\Big)\Big[E[X]+1\Big]=\Big({1\over n+2}\Big)(n\theta+1)={n\theta\over n+2}+{1\over n+2}$
Since this is not equal to $\theta$, this is a biased estimator. 
Now, check: $\lim_{n\to \infty}E\Big[\frac{X+1}{n+2}\Big]=\lim_{n\to \infty}\Big({n\theta\over n+2}+{1\over n+2}\Big)=\theta$. 
So, this is asymptotically unbiased.

I wonder whether I was doing right about this problem.

Comment: Who does $X$ depend on the sample points?

Comment: Your first "equality" has a typo, at the very least. The approach is ok.

Comment: @cardinal Got you. I have already fixed it.

Comment: This estimator is UNbiased for one value of theta.

Comment: @Did I am thinking you were talking about when $\theta={1\over 2}$. But in the textbook, I was just asked to show this is a biased estimator.

Comment: This is what I am saying: the book is wrong since, for one value of theta, the estimator has no bias.

Comment: @Did: I see the point you are raising, though, generally speaking, the definition for unbiasedness of a statistical estimator entails that it is true uniformly in $\theta$, i.e., $\delta(X)$ is an unbiased estimator of a parameter $\theta$ iff $\mathbb E_{\theta} \delta(X) = \theta$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$. See, for example, E. L. Lehmann and G. Casella, *Theory of Point Estimation*, 2nd ed., Springer, 1998, pg. 5.

Comment: @cardinal Point taken. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

You are. Alternatively, you could have shown that the bias of your estimator is not zero.

$\mathbb{E}(\frac{X+1}{n+2}-\theta)=\frac{1}{n+2}\mathbb{E}(X+1-\theta n -2\theta)=\frac{1-2\theta}{n+2}$ implying estimator is biased.

Working with the bias rather than with the estimator is useful in the more general setting where the parameter you are estimating is a random variable rather than a constant.